# Remove Eclipse src folder

Tags: eclipse

Currently, my project has a folder called "(default package)" which is inside a src folder in Eclipse. This folder has the symbol for a src folder in eclipse.  When I run .scp, it complains that src is not a regular file. I think the reason is my directory structure - so how do I remove src and leave (default package) as my src folder?

Note, src just seems to hold (default package).

Comment: 1. Don't use the default package. Just don't. Choose a real package name and use that. 2. Look at the corresponding directory structure on disk to see what's actually going on.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can choose your source folder instead of default folder.

```
Project Properties >> Java Build Path >> Source Tab
```

[image: Change source folder]